# HTML5 LocalStorage to maintain session across pages/tabs under same domain

Tags: javascript, html, session-state

Anyone provide me way, I can use HTML5 LocalStorage to use in Javascript to maintain session between server and client to keep track of session Timeout which will redirect the all tabs or pages in session Expired page.

Is there any way(Other than this) i can maintain session across the page/tabs under same domain to keep track of Session Timeout.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: LocalStorage is … local. It isn't connected to the server at all. It doesn't seem like an appropriate tool for the job.

Comment: I need some global object which i can refer across same parent webpages/tabs so only asking for localStorage

Answer (score 2):

You have not posted any code so the only think I can do for you is just show you a generic example which may not completely suit your requirement but will give an idea on how you could do it:

```
// show last settings pane if it's set
if ( localStorage.activePill ) {
    $('.nav-pill-control > li').removeClass('active');
    $('.nav-pill-control > li > a[href="' + localStorage.activePill + '"]').parent().addClass('active');
    $('.nav-pill-pane').hide();
    $(localStorage.activePill).show();
}
```

Comment: The question said "to maintain session between server and client". How does this involve the server?

Answer (score 0):

The sessionStorage object is equal to the localStorage object, except that it stores the data for only one session. The data is deleted when the user closes the specific browser tab.

Comment: While that is true, I'm not sure how it answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

In HTML5 you can use session to pass object from page to another:

// Save data to sessionStorage

```
sessionStorage.setItem('key', 'value');
```

// Get saved data from sessionStorage

```
var data = sessionStorage.getItem('key');
```

// Remove saved data from sessionStorage

```
sessionStorage.removeItem('key')
```

[More Information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)

Comment: How does this help "to maintain session between server and client" that the question asks about?